# How to multiply matrix having different size (without knowing exactly the size they will have)?

Tags: matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array, matrix-multiplication, multiplication

I have to multiply 2 matrices (scalar multiplication) that have different sizes. For instance, the 1st has size *n*-by-*m* and the 2nd *n+1*-by-*m+1*. The fact is that it is not always the case. I mean, sometimes the first has size *n+1*-by-*m+1* and the 2nd *n*-by-*m* or *n+2*-by-*m+2* etc...

Example:

```
a = [ 1 2 3; 
      4 5 6]; 

b = [ 1 2 3; 
      4 5 6; 
      7 8 9]
```

I would like Matlab to check the size of each matrix, then multiply them using the smallest size available between the 2 i.e. ignoring the last rows and columns of the bigger matrix (or similarly, adding rows and columns of `0` to the smaller matrix).

With the example inputs I would like to obtain:

```
c = [1  4  9; 
     16 25 36]
```

or

```
c = [1  4  9; 
     16 25 36; 
     0  0  0]
```

How can I write this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find the number of rows and columns of your final matrix:

```
n = min(size(a,1), size(b,1));
m = min(size(a,2), size(b,2));
```

Then extract only the relevant sections of `a` and `b` (using the `:` operator) for your multiplication:

```
c = a(1:n,1:m).*b(1:n,1:m)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only consider dot product, it means that size(a) must equal size(b), which allows to simply restrain the size of b, you can use a simple if statement if you like. For example:

```
if all(size(b) == size(a))
   answer = a.*b
else 
   minsize(:,1) = min(size(a,1),size(b,1));
   minsize(:,2) = min(size(a,2),size(b,2));
   answer = a(1:minsize(:,1),1:minsize(:,2)).*a(1:minsize(:,1),1:minsize(:,2));
end
```

I don't think this is easiest way to do it, but it is simple to understand :)

Comment: Why do you need the `if`? this won't break when `a` and `b` have the same size. Also, I think it is the easiest way to do it. Also why do you do `minsize(:,1)` etc instead of just `minsize(1)`?

Comment: Actually, I mis-read the problem and thought it was matrix product (instead of dot product), so I began writing and realized I went the wrong way half way. So I thought I might as well use the if to show my understanding of the problem. It is definitely not needed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not always sure which one of the matrix is bigger, then I thought to use:

```
if size (a) > size (b)
   a = a(1:size(b,1),1:size(b,2));
elseif size (a) < size (b)
   b = b (1: size (a,1),1:size(a,2));
end
```

It seems to work like this.

Comment: This assumes that the one matrix will be larger than the other in *both* columns and rows. But what is `a` is *n*-by-*m* and `b` is *n-1*-by-*m+1*? The other solutions provided here are more general and they do not alter your original `a` or `b` to find the correct `c`

Comment: I agree to Dan's solution, it is universal correct and simple. My method is essentially the same, but it would take more time to compute.

Comment: I agree, both your solutions are better because they do not alter the original a and b. 
Dan, a little specification: in your solution the dim of m should be 2 and not 1, because it is referred to the column (yes, the 2 matrix could change both in rows and columns)